# Appcelerator: Raising an event

Tags: iphone, appcelerator

I am using Titanium Appcelerator, I want to refresh Window/TableView/ScrollView manually. How can I do that? Is there anyway to raise event?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appcelerator. Problems with refresh function for page. Please help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612136/appcelerator-problems-with-refresh-function-for-page-please-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a common architectural problem, you should separate out the
>   function of creating the table and loading the table's data. [***Quoted***]

Please see: [Problems with refresh function for page, in Appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5613006/488434)